# Does dart support client SSL/TLS connections yet?

Tags: dart

I am thinking of writing an Apple Push Notification server using Dart.  Does Dart support client side SSL/TLS certificates?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Dart VM now supports SSL/TLS, and HTTPS.

See http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3950 and http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3593 which are now closed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dart supports SSL/TLS client connections using [SecureSocket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/SecureSocket.html). It also supports secure server sockets using [SecureServerSocket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/SecureServerSocket.html) to (use this if you need to listen on a secure port on the VM).

Note that the ordinary HttpClient will automatically handle HTTPS for your browser connections so no extra code is needed in these cases.

Comment: I need socket level TLS with a client side certificate opening the connection and not a https socket.  Thanks anyway.  I will file a bug.

Comment: Nice, please post the bug so I can star it. Need the same functionality

Comment: The Dart VM now supports SSL/TLS! Woohoo!