# Enable TLS on open socket (STARTTLS)

Tags: ssl, dart, starttls, dart-io

Looks like SSL/TLS support has recently been [added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882158/does-dart-support-client-ssl-tls-connections-yet) to Dart via the [SecureSocket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/SecureSocket.html) class, which is great.

So, for example this

```
SecureSocket.connect(_host, _port).then(
        (Socket socket) {
          ...
```

opens a socket with TLS enabled right away. However, what I'd like to do is open a regular (not secure) socket, send and receive some unencrypted data first, and enable TLS on it later.

Here's how it can be done in PHP:

```
$socket = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr);
// ... do some unencrypted stuff...
stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
```

Any way to do this in Dart?

EDIT: I guess what I'm looking for is a Dart implementation of [STARTTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like the `secure` method in the [SecureSocket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/SecureSocket.html) documentation is exactly what you're looking for (assuming you want to use a client-side handshake, otherwise see `secureServer`):

> ```
> Future<SecureSocket> secure(Socket socket, {host, 
>        bool sendClientCertificate: false, String certificateName, bool
>        onBadCertificate(X509Certificate certificate)})
> ```
>
> Takes an already connected socket and starts client side TLS handshake
>   to make the communication secure.

Comment: Works. Can't believe I didn't see that in the doc. Thanks!